# Custom button titlelabel's text sets itself back to default value on tap

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, custom-controls

My custom button contains a value that's updated on swipe. But when I tap on it, instead of keeping that value, it sets back to the default value that was set either in Interface Builder, or through `[button00 setText:@"default value" forState:UIControlStateNormal]`.

Any idea how I could keep the latest updated value?

Comment: How exactly is the value updated when the swipe occurs?

Comment: I have an default value, let's say @"1900". Swipes upward adds 10 to it, and swipes downward removes 10. Let's say the value is updated through swipes until @"1920", when I tap it, it will be reset to @"1900".

Comment: The value is updated by converting the string using [button.titleLabel.text integerValue], and setting it back using     [Button00.titleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", button00IntegerValue+10]];

Comment: Ah, I see.  Call `setText:@"..." forState:UIControlStateNormal` for each of those updates.

Comment: Aw. Updating the initial value, that totally makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't modify the label text; call `setText:forState:` on the `UIButton` for any update.